# why can't I compare Exception objects for equality?

Tags: java

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Objects;
public class FooMain {

    private static Exception foo() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int N = 2;
        Exception es[] = new Exception[N];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
            es[i] = foo();
        System.out.printf("Exceptions are equal? %b\n", Objects.equals(es[0], es[1]));
        for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
            System.out.printf("follows exception %d:\n", i);
            es[i].printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above outputs:

```
 [java] Exceptions are equal? false
 [java] follows exception 0:
 [java] follows exception 1:
 [java] java.lang.Exception
 [java]     at FooMain.foo(FooMain.java:6)
 [java]     at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:17)
 [java] java.lang.Exception
 [java]     at FooMain.foo(FooMain.java:6)
 [java]     at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:17)
```

Comment: What kind of equality are you checking?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that the two exceptions have identical stack traces (see my comment on the accepted answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exception class inherits its `equals()` method from `Object` and doesn't override it. You create new Exception instances each time which are different objects in the memory. Even though their stack traces are the same, they still have different object allocation in the memory and with the default equals() method, they are not the same.

However, you can define your custom exception class and override `equals()`.

Comment: Given that `StackTraceElement` overrides `equals` it seems weird that `Exception` does not override `equals` as well. At any rate I finally resorted at iterating and comparing over the two arrays of `StackTraceElement` returned by `getStackTrace`.

Comment: In the Oracle JDK the stack trace is lazily initialized. I assume the eager stack trace determination would take too much time.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually comparing them but:

```
es[0] and es[1] are not the same object
```

From [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) documentation:

The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

You could compare them by hash code:

```
Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(es[0])) == Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(es[1]))
```

And yet they wouldn't be the same object.

I think that you want to compare classes so this should work:

```
es[0].getClass().equals(es[1].getClass())
```

Comment: I like the suggestion of comparing the class instances. I've also compared the toString result (which, by default is "<Class>: <message>")

Answer (score 0):

Exception class does not have its own equals method implementation. So, it just checks for reference variable. Since there are two different exception objects created,hence different reference variable, it is showing equals as false.

To show more about how it works, try as below, have a static exception (not sure of use case but just to understand why it fails)

```
private static Exception myStaticException = new Exception();

private static Exception foo() {
    try {
        throw myStaticException;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

....

Comment: Implement means provide your own implementation of any super class method. Inherit does not mean a class has equals implementation. Please check