# Why do Exception classes in Java NOT implement equals method?

Tags: java

Why do `Exception` classes (like [RuntimeException](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/RuntimeException.java)) not implement `equals()` method?

For example, the [output](http://ideone.com/Qoyhv3) for this code is `false`:

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final RuntimeException e1 = new RuntimeException("e");
        final RuntimeException e2 = new RuntimeException("e");
        System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why `equals()` is not implemented? Seems to me it would be fairly useful.

Edit: Let me expand on the question, since it seems that most people believe an `equals()` implementation would not be useful.

I would like to know, why Exceptions should be treated differently than normal objects and only be matched if its the same instance. Does it not have enough information about itself to compare with other objects. For example, the underlying [StackTraceElement](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StackTraceElement.java#StackTraceElement.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), which I presume stores the call stack, already implements an `equals` method.

Is there something in the definition of Exceptions that stop them from implementing an equals method based on their attributes?

Comment: Why do you need to compare `Exception`s?  I've never needed to compare `Exception`s.

Comment: If you'd like to compare `RuntimeException` objects, create your own subclass that overrides `equals`.

Comment: Those exceptions would have different stack traces, so would you really consider them equal?

Comment: But the StackTraceElement itself implements an equals method, but its not bubbled upto the Exception. Its okay if the stack traces are actually different, but I'm puzzled why it lacks an implementation completely.

Comment: @asteri could you elaborate on "must be declared in different stack frames, by definition"

Comment: Ask the developers. You're asking in the wrong place. All you'll get here is more or less uninformed opinion. But I agree with @rgettman. I've never compared exceptions in over 20 years of OOP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are methods and classes in JDK which most programmers have never used in their careers, but they are still there. Similarly, if a method implementation was omitted, I'm sure there was a reason. I'm trying to get at the reason for such a design.

Comment: As for the use case, I've have a convoluted piece of code which stores exceptions in a map. I'm trying to compare the contents of two maps. I can obviously unpack the map and check just the instances of the exceptions, but it got me wondering why is the implementation absent by default.

Comment: @SANDeveloper: Well the default implementation is `Object.equals`. `e1.equals(e1);` returns `true`. There is simply no "natural" equality between exceptions since they are called at different times, in different contexts, in different programs,...

Comment: possible duplicate of [why can't I compare Exception objects for equality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596941/why-cant-i-compare-exception-objects-for-equality)

Comment: So general consensus is that 2 Exceptions will never be equal regardless of their constituents. I agree with that, though I still wonder why did Java's designers not let an overridden equals decide rather than depend on the crude Object.equals(). Unless there's a much better answer, I'll mark @CommuSoft's attempt as correct since she/he got their first.

Comment: "Similarly, if a method implementation was omitted, I'm sure there was a reason." As a general rule, no, there usually aren't reasons why things *don't* exist. The default state of affairs is for things not to exist. Nobody has to do anything to make a method *not be there*. Often the answer to "why doesn't X exist?" is simply "nobody ever thought of it before". That's a lot more common than an idea being thought of, but rejected.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that doesn't seem true at all for a project like the JDK itself. While writing the scores of Exception classes defined in java.lang, did not a single developer think whether it will be appropriate to override the equals implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `Exception`s are ordinary class instances. Exceptions can maintain a state.

For instance one can claim that an exception thrown at one specific line with a specific message is not equal to an exception thrown at the next line.

Even if the error is thrown on the same line with the same call stack but different runs of programs, one can say the exceptions aren't the same... For instance the first program can be called with:

```
java -jar program.jar "arg1" & java -jar program.jar "arg2"
```

The programs have a different `pid`, are thrown at a different time stamp,...

You can however implement the `equals` method yourself using inheritance (for your own defined `Exception`s):

```
public class WeirdException extends Exception {

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof WeirdException);
    }

}
```

After all, the stacktrace is only "stored" in the `Exception` at construction time, a perfectly valid java program is the following:

```
public class MyClass {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Exception ex = new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:15)
```

In other words, `throw` has not much to do with `Exception`. `throw` merely means an "alternative `return`". It has nothing to do with storing the stack trace,...

Comment: That is not an equality test, but merely an instance of test.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In the case the Exception doesn't contain a state, that's more or less the same. But the first question one needs to ask (this is documented in the answer), is when two `Exception`s are equal. Do they need to share the same stacktrace? The same process? The same timestamp...

Comment: I can see what you're getting at. But on the first line did you mean Exceptions aren't ordinary class instances?

Comment: @SANDeveloper: no, `Exception`s are the same sort of classes as `ArrayList`,... Only at the construction of an `Exception` (for the sake of argument) at the constructor level, the stacktrace is serialized and stored in the exception, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There's a simple explanation: Two different instances of `Exception` are in no sense equal.

What's the meaning of *equality* of exceptions? If two objects are equal, they are in some way semantically identitcal. But two instances of `Exception` are always semantically different - either the exception occured at another place (i.e., the stacktrace is different), or, most likely, at another time, i.e. under different circumstances.

Two different instances of `Exception`s should never be equal, simply because they cannot stand for the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, although `Exception` doesn't override `equals`, it does have an implementation, the one inherited from `Object`, which compares identity.

For most cases, you can implement an exception comparer, e.g. logging only the first occurrence, or compare to a template, although I guess stack traces are not comparable in this case. You'll have to define specific comparers for certain exception classes if you want to support more than the base fields.

Exceptions aren't much prone to value semantics. What would you do if they had, use them as hash table keys? In that case, you can implement a wrapper class which `equals` and `hashCode` behave like that.