# Which is better among ShouldBe vs ShouldEqual for comparing two exception objects

Tags: scala, exception, scalatest, assertion

I have a code which returns exception object from future

```
val actual = doSomething(x).failed.futureValue
val expected = new SomeException()
```

Which is the best way to assert them

actual shouldEqual expected
OR
 actual shouldBe expected

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no difference, but `shouldEqual` is commonly used when you define your own instance of `Equality` trait. So, it's up to you what method to choose.

**Update**

But you won't be able to compare exception because exceptions from Standard Library of Java (and Scala) [don't override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596981/9128490) `equals()`. But it will be OK if you use your own exceptions with overriden method `equals()`.